# Finding the index of current element in a map function

Tags: haskell

I have a list with elements that can have duplicates and i want to

map a function for example: `map (\x -> f (5 + (elemIndex x l))) l`
The problem is that if the list has duplicate elements `elemIndex` returns the index of the first one. I want it to be the index of `x` in `l` ,where `x` is the current element.

I guess I am looking for a function to replace `elemIndex` in my code

Comment: Do you actually need the elements of `l`, or just its length?

Comment: yea the function `f` is just for the example in my case its something that uses the elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `zip` your list with a list of indices before `map`ping. There also is a shorthand `zipWith` for `zip` followed by `map`.

```
zipWith (\i x -> f (5 + i)) [0 ..] l
```